# c++ namespaceの仕様について

Tags: c++

下記コードを実行する際、namespace でくくったはずの関数がそのまま使用できてしまうのは
namespace の仕様なのでしょうか？
namespace Test 内で宣言した Vector2 構造体を使用しているか否かで
コンパイル時の成否が変わってしまっています。
AddVector() には Test:: を付けても付けなくてもコンパイルが成功してしまっているのが解せません。

AddVector() 自身を　namespace Util{} など別名でくくると
コンパイル時
Util::AddVecro();    // NG
Test::Util::AddVector();    // OK
となります。

```
#include <stdlib.h>

namespace Test {
    struct Vector2 {
        float x;
        float y;
    };

    float AddFloat(float a, float b) {
        return a + b;
    }

    Vector2 AddVector(const Vector2& srcA, const Vector2& srcB) {
        Vector2 add;
        add.x = srcA.x + srcB.x;
        add.y = srcA.y + srcB.y;
        return add;
    }
}    // namespace Test

int main(int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    float floatTest[2];
    float floatAdd1 = AddFloat(floatTest[0], floatTest[1]);    // NG
    float floatAdd2 = Test::AddFloat(floatTest[0], floatTest[1]);    // OK

    Test::Vector2 test[2];
    Test::Vector2 add;
    add = AddVector(test[0], test[1]);    // OK

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

sayuriさん回答の通り、C++言語の ADL(argument dependent name lookup) という仕様によって`Test::AddVector`が自動的に探し出されています。

---

質問中にあるようなソースコードをコンパイルエラーとしたい場合、下記のように入れ子の名前空間と`using namespace`宣言を組み合わせることで、明示的にADLを禁止できます。

```
namespace Test {  
  struct Vector2 {
    float x;
    float y;
  };

  namespace adl_barrier {
    // 入れ子名前空間内で関数を定義しておき...
    Vector2 AddVector(const Vector2& srcA, const Vector2& srcB) {
      Vector2 add;
      add.x = srcA.x + srcB.x;
      add.y = srcA.y + srcB.y;
      return add;
    }
  }
  // ...改めて入れ子名前空間を取り込む
  using namespace adl_barrier;
} // namespace Test

int main(int, char *[]) {
  Test::Vector2 test[2];
  Test::Vector2 add;
  add = AddVector(test[0], test[1]);  // NG!
  // ADLは機能しないためAddVectorは見つからない

  // 明示的に名前空間修飾を行えばもちろんOK
  // add = Test::AddVector(test[0], test[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

[ADL; 実引数依存の名前探索](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%AE%9F%E5%BC%95%E6%95%B0%E4%BE%9D%E5%AD%98%E3%81%AE%E5%90%8D%E5%89%8D%E6%8E%A2%E7%B4%A2)という機能です。

> ```
> add = AddVector(test[0], test[1]);
> ```

ですが、第一引数`test[0]`の型は`Test::Vector2`ですので、`Test::AddVector()`が検索されます。

Wikipediaでも説明されていますが、

```
std::cout << "hello, world.\n";
```

ですら、名前空間を指定していないにも関わらず`std::operator<<()`を呼び出しているわけで、知らず知らずのうちに使っています。

Comment: 実際は namespace を自前ライブラリで用意しており、それをアプリケーションで
使用する際にソースをパッと見ただけでライブラリ側の関数だと分かればいいな
程度で使用していたのですが、コンパイルエラーが出てくれないならいまいち
目的は果たせそうにありません。
返答ありがとうございました。